# How to run timer job as well as event receiver on the same ABC Library in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, timer-jobs

I have an ABC Library, in this timer job import data from the external portal library and event receiver also created on "ItemAdded" that set the fixed properties when uploading documents to ABC library..

My problem is that when timer job is running, then I am facing a issue in the ABC library like:

Event receiver fired and updated fixed properties on managed fields of a document instead of properties of imported document of the external library.

To resolve this I have put checks if the field is empty, then only event receiver set the properties on managed fields.

Even, in this case also some time event receiver set the fixed properties in managed fields of ABC library. Kindly help me I am facing this issue for very long time...

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable event firing in event receiver by EventFiringEnabled property.

Check below thread for sample.

https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/